Is there a way for CulebraTester2_Client to record and generate code for actions performed on Android device ? like Culebra
I can run Culebratester2-client server and API MRIN9 are working fine. Is there a way to record and generate code like Culebra GUI ?
System: Windows 10, Python 3.12, AndroidViewClient, Culebratester2_client, Android Samsung A05.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you run culebra --gui --use-uiautomator-helper ... and have CulebraTester2-public server running it will generate python code compatible with that backend.

Perfect, thank you.
